# Minimum distance between factorials and powers of 2

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

Let's define for a positive integer $n$: $$a(n) = \min \{|n! - 2^m| : m \in \mathbb N \}.$$ Does there exist a good asymptotic lower bound for the values $a(n)$ for large $n$? In particular, is the following conjecture true?:

> Conjecture: For all positive $k$, $a(n)$ is bigger than a constant multiple of $2^{((\log n)^k)}$.

Comment: More interesting case is $$a(n,t)=\mathsf{min}\{|n!-2^{m_2}3^{m_3}\dots p_{t-1}^{m_{t-1}} p_{t}^{m_{t}}|:\forall i\{1,\dots,t\},m_i\in\Bbb N\}?$$ Particularly if $t\leq(\log n)^{\log\log n}$ held true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $2^r$ be the highest power of 2 dividing $n!$. If $m$ minimizes your expression, it's easy to see that $m \geq r$. So your expression, which is non-zero for $n \geq 3$, will be divisible by and hence at least $2^r$. Now your conjecture (and more) follows from (e.g.)
$$r = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\rfloor} \geq \frac{n}{2}-1.$$

Comment: How about for $$a(n,t)=\mathsf{min}\{|n!-2^{m_2}3^{m_3}\dots p_{t-1}^{m_{t-1}} p_{t}^{m_{t}}|:\forall i\{1,\dots,t\},m_i\in\Bbb N\}?$$ Particularly if $t\leq(\log n)^{\log\log n}$ held true?

Comment: The conjecture is $2^{(log\, n)^k}$, not $(2^{log\, n})^k$ and this is trivial only for $k=1$.

Comment: It is not $n^k$, but $2^{n/2}>2^{\log^k n}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry, you are right.